What the fundamental difference between an async code polling a cancellation token and registering a callback to be executed when the caller requests?
I'm watching (not for the first time) Working with Asynchrony Generically: A Tour of C++ Executors (part 1 and 2), which is about P2300.
With respect to cancellation support, Eric Niebler says that the calling code should declare a std::stop_source, call get_token() on it, and pass the resulting std::stop_token to the async code to be started. Then, at any moment, the caller can call request_stop on the std::stop_source.
The author of the async code, should write things such that a prompt reaction to that request is guaranteed. To do so, Eric say, they can do one of two things:

periodically poll the std::stop_token that it was given by the caller, I assume via stop_requested(), and react accordingly,
or by registering a callback to be executed when the caller requests a stop.

While I can imagine the solution 1 fairly easily, I don't quite get

how the solution 2 would look like,
and (maybe this is not really about the P2300, but asynchronicity in general) why does it make a difference? After all, doesn't the "when the caller requests a stop" imply some kind of polling going on somwhere?

Is the somewhere what makes the difference?




‘Async code polling’ is a contradiction in terms.

@user207421, please, expand on that.

"How the solution 2 would look like".
"Polling" the stop state is a good thing for threads that consume CPU -- they are in some loop calculating something, and every now and then they check the stop state. So far, so good.
However, threads aren't necessarily using CPU -- they might be sitting in a wait-call, waiting for something to happen. This means they can't poll anything. And no, you don't want to just run your waits in a loop with a 10ms timeout or something like that so it can check the stop state.
In many cases, that might actually be an event loop of some sort. In this case, the callback that's registered with the stop-system would be used to send a "quit"-event to the event loop.
If an event loop is not used, we could still implement the waits in a way that they can be cancelled from the outside, which is then triggered by the callbacks, allowing the thread to wake up and react (usually by just throwing an exception indicating the cancellation).
Things could also be combined: your callback could simply wake up the thread, and the thread would just check the stop state before looking for actual work. It's really depends on what the thread does and what's convenient. At the end of the day, the callbacks are meant for situation where just having a stop-yes/no boolean isn't enough, and the thread needs some move involved kick to notice the stop.
